# AddEventListener by default when class method is called

Tags: javascript, constructor, addeventlistener

I have a class and constructor in which I am trying to add event listener to a button when the element is created and I succeded but what I actually wanted to do is add that event listener to the button element when that button is created without the need to call handleOrder function.

I cant find a way to do it by default when the button is created (in my case .order button). I tried a lot of solutions by adding the querySelectorAll in constructor and with forEach add the event listener but it does not work.

```
class Shop {
  constructor(products = []) {
    this.products = products;
  }
  handleOrder = () => {
    this.order = document.querySelectorAll(".order");
    this.order.forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener("click", e => {
        console.log(e.target.parentElement);
      });
    });
  };

  addProduct = ({ name, price, description }) => {
    let template = `
        <h1>${name}</h1>
        <h3>${price}$</h3>
        <p>${description}</p>
        <button class="order">Order</button>
      `;

    const container = document.createElement("div");
    container.classList.add("shop-item");
    container.innerHTML = template;
    document.body.appendChild(container);
  };
}

const myShop = new Shop();

myShop.addProduct({
  name: "Beer",
  price: 30,
  description: "This is a beer",
});
myShop.addProduct({
  name: "Beer 2",
  price: 3,
  description: "Another beer",
});
myShop.handleOrder();
```

I also tried adding the event listener in addProduct function but that also did not work or all of my solutions were not written how they are supposed to be written or what I wrote now is the only solution to this. I don't know, I need help.

So is there a way to add that event listener to the button by default, since there would be a lot of items in the "shop".

Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: In the end of `addProduct` method, look for the last button.order and add it the EventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the button programmatically, instead of declaring it in your `template` and append it to the end of the container before appending the container to the document. You then have reference to the node which you can add a listener to.

This has the added advantage of giving you access to all the product data from the passed object to use in the `onClick` function without further querying.

```js
  addProduct = ({ name, price, description }) => {
    let template = `
        <h1>${name}</h1>
        <h3>${price}$</h3>
        <p>${description}</p>
      `;

    const container = document.createElement("div");
    container.classList.add("shop-item");
    container.innerHTML = template;
    
    const orderButton = document.createElement("button");
    orderButton.innerHTML = "order";
    orderButton.classList.add("order");
    container.appendChild(orderButton);
    orderButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(name);
    });
    
    document.body.appendChild(container);
   
  };




addProduct({
  name: "Beer",
  price: 30,
  description: "This is a beer",
});
addProduct({
  name: "Beer 2",
  price: 3,
  description: "Another beer",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work

```
  document.body.appendChild(container).onclick = (a) => {
        console.log(a)
    }
```